Change font size in pop-up window
When I click on "save as" a pop up window comes up. How do I resize the font in this window? I have resized the icons in "my favourites" using about:configuration. Is there a setting in about:configuration to change pop up window font also, or is there another way? I can resize the box by dragging, but the font stays the same size.

Have you tried Tweaks -> Fonts -> Interface Text
